# Socket.io Cross domain

Tags: socket.io, cross-domain

I have problems with cross-domains when build my app with NodeJS-Socket.io.

Here is my server:

```
console.log("Starting server...")
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').Server(app),
io = require('socket.io')(server),
compress = require('compression')(),
sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

app.use(compress);
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('Setting configuration');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://fo-member.dev.game.com");
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', true);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
        next();
    }
);

server.listen(11081);
io.set("origins","http://fo-member.dev.game.com");
console.log("Server started listening on 11081");
```

It runs on port 11081. I have configure the apache to forward from port 80 to node server, like:

```
NameVirtualHost fo-node.dev.game.com:80
<VirtualHost fo-node.dev.game.com:80>
ServerName fo-node.dev.game.com
ServerAdmin contact@game.com

ErrorLog "logs\game-fo-node.error.log"
CustomLog "logs\game-fo-node.access.log" common
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On 

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:11081/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:11081/
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have a frontend server which is running on 11080 (it is tomcat) and also be forwared port by apache on the domain: http://fo-member.dev.game.com

On the frontend, I am able to get the socket.io/socket.js by:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fo-node.dev.game.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It looks fine for now. But when I do the connect action from frontend, like:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://fo-node.dev.game.com/notify');

            socket.on("connect", function() {
                console.log("connected");
                // Let the server know who is connected...
                socket.emit("user", { Id: 101 });
            });
            socket.on('update', function (data) {
                // Do something cool like update badges/status/etc...
                console.log(data);
            });
```

The client console show me error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fo-node.dev.game.com/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401700586028-90. Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials.
```

Further more, I already added the header configure inside apache allows cross-domains:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www.)?(fo-member.dev.game.com|fo-rest.dev.game.com|fo-node.dev.game.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0$1
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

This is the request header:

```
Request URL:http://fo-node.dev.game.com/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401703622820-0
    Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
    Origin:http://fo-member.dev.game.com
    Referer:http://fo-member.dev.game.com/
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
    Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
    EIO:2
    transport:polling
    t:1401703622820-0
```

I appreciate for your reading and may be you guys can let me know my mistakes.

Comment: I'm not an expert but the error is about missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', add res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); would not be enough to make it work ?

Comment: If not would be great to analyse the tracks of request and response, i don't understand why when you connect, you have credentials to true.

Comment: @Jujuleder: I added the request-header, hope it gives more information.